# Raphael: how do you change properties during an animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, raphael

I don't know if this is possible but it seems like the sort of thing that should be possible - somehow. What I want to do is change the property of an object while that object is being animated.

Consider a simple example of a clockface with a ticking and animated seconds hand. If the clockface can be freely rotated by the user I would want the second had to follow the rotation while it is being animated between ticks.

Some code that illustrates what I am trying to do:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en_US" xml:lang="en_US">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/raphael.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var paper = Raphael("Display", $("#Display").width(), $("#Display").height());
                var centreX = $("#Display").width() / 2;
                var centreY = $("#Display").height() / 2;
                var radius = 0.9 * Math.min($("#Display").height(), $("#Display").width()) / 2;
                var rotation = 0;
                var seconds = 0;

                var s = "M"+centreX+","+centreY+"L"+centreX+","+(centreY-0.8*radius);
                var pointer = paper.path(s);

                clockface = paper.set();

                for(i=1; i<=12; i++) {
                    sn=Math.sin(i * 30 * Math.PI / 180);
                    cs=Math.cos(i * 30 * Math.PI / 180);
                    t = paper.text(centreX+(0.9*sn*radius), centreY-(0.9*cs*radius), i).attr({"font-size":28});
                    clockface.push(t);
                }

                // Non-animated tick every second
//              setInterval(function() {
//                  seconds += 1;
//                  pointer.transform("r" + (seconds * 6 + rotation) + " " + centreX + " " + centreY);
//              }, 1000);

                // Animated Tick every 5 seconds
                setInterval(function() {
                    seconds += 5;
                    pointer.animate({transform: "r" + (seconds * 6 + rotation) + " " + centreX + " " + centreY}, 3000, "backIn");
                }, 5000);

                $("#Display").mousemove(function(pos) {
                    rotation = pos.pageX * 360 / 500;
                    clockface.transform("r" + rotation + "," + centreX + "," + centreY);
                    pointer.transform("r" + (seconds * 6 + rotation) + " " + centreX + " " + centreY);
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="Display" style="width: 500px; height: 500px;">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

While the clock is ticking away wave the mouse over the clockface to rotate it. You will see that the seconds hand does not follow the rotation during the animation. I had thought that I would be able to do this by adding the hand into the set and rotating the whole set while the hand is being animated but that just resets the hand's position.

Is it possible to get to what I am trying tho acheive?

Comment: Not sure if this is possible in an easy way. It feels like you probably need SVG Group support, which Raphael doesn't really do with sets (Snap.svg supports this, but has less support for older browsers if thats a concern). If you could only use Raph and Jquery, I wonder if you could use a combination of raphael and css transformations, but feels a bit wrong :). Maybe someone else will come up with a clever idea.

Comment: Just thinking, you could possibly separate the display function out, and update it all on mousemove or setInterval every second, maybe, but you would lose the easing stuff.

Comment: @Ian. This is essentially what I have now done. Using a setInterval every 1/10th second I calculate and update the pointer position and implement a basic ease-in animation. It works but lacks the flexibility of doing it directly in Raphael.